# Implementation of ungetch() in Clang

Tags: c++, clang

I wanted to ask is there any code available to implement `ungetch()` function from `conio.h` header file in Clang compiler. I want to compile my code using Clang which has to use the `ungetch` function. I guess this function has no implementation in Clang. Is there any similar function supported by Clang ?

Comment: The `conio.h` header is *not* a standard header, so it doesn't exist for clang. The console-IO library was mostly used in the old MS-DOS days.

Comment: You might be able to use the curses (or ncurses) library which includes IO functions like getch/ungetch, but it is not a drop-in replacement for conio-based stuff.

Comment: Are you using Clang on windows, or are you trying to compile your code with Clang in Mac OS X or Linux (or some other non-Windows OS)?

Comment: I am using clang on linux. Use of curses (or ncurses) is of no help. I have tried using these libraries. The errors were :
/home/arpit/Downloads/refinal.cpp:81: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/arpit/Downloads/refinal.cpp:81: undefined reference to `wgetch'
/home/arpit/Downloads/refinal.cpp:93: undefined reference to `ungetch'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @SurbhiSingh That's because (n)curses is an external library that you have to explicitly link with, it's not enough to just include header files. For both gcc and clang you have to add the `-l` (small-letter L) to tell the linker to add a library: `-lcurses` (or `-lncurses`).